# created a function that reverses the contents of an array of double in C? but not working

Tags: c

i wanted to create a function that reverses the contents of an array of double in C but its not working
My function is not returning the reversed array? Please help

```
//Reverse the content of an array of double

#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 5
double *reverse(double *func[],int n);
int main()
{
 int i;
 double *arr[SIZE]; 
 printf("Please enter 5 numbers\n");
 for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++) {

    scanf("%lf",arr[i]); // takes the the content of array
 }

  double arr = reverse(&arr,SIZE); // takes the return value from the function

 for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++) {

    printf("%.2lf\n",arr[i]);
 }
}

double *reverse(double *func[],int n)
{
 int i,j;
 static double *base[SIZE];
 for(i=4,j=0;i>=0,j<n;i--,j++) {

    base[j] = func[i];      // reverses the content of array

 }

 return *base;

}
```

I guess there is a problem in my function, but i am not able to find it

Comment: Kindly show your research / debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your program cannot even be compiled. For instance, it has two conflicting definitions of `arr` in the same function. Why do you expect it to run, especially correctly?

Comment: `double *arr[SIZE];` is **not** an array of double.

Comment: You don't have an array of doubles, you have an array of pointers doubles.  And oops!  You forgot to allocate space for them.   I suggest you change it to use an array of doubles.  You don't need the extra level of indirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code. Most important this:

```
double *arr[SIZE];
```

That is **not** an **array of double** (it is an array of pointers to double). That misunderstanding seem to go through all the program and cause several other mistakes.

For instance this:

```
scanf("%lf",arr[i]);
```

Here `arr[i]` is an **uninitialized pointer** so scanning into it is undefined behavior.

Further, your function call suffers from the array mistake as well.

A more correct version of your code could be:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 5
void reverse(double* d, int n);

int main()
{
  int i;
  double arr[SIZE];   // Array of double

  printf("Please enter %d numbers\n", SIZE);
  for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++) 
  {
    scanf("%lf", &arr[i]); // TODO: Check scanf return value....
              // ^ Notice the & (i.e. address-of)
  }

  reverse(arr, SIZE);  // Just pass arr as it will decay into a double pointer

  for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++) 
  {
    printf("%.2lf\n",arr[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}

void reverse(double* d, int n) // Just pass a pointer to first double in the array
{
  int i, j=0;
  double temp;
  for(i=n-1; i>j; i--,j++)  // Stop when you reach the middle of the array
  {
     // Swap using a temp variable
     temp = d[j];
     d[j] = d[i];
     d[i] = temp;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void reverse(double *arr,int n)
{

    for(int i=0;i<n/2;i++)
    {
       double temp = arr[i];
       arr[i] = arr[n-i-1];
       arr[n-i-1] = arr[i];
    }
}
```